# How to filter the ids of objects in two different Lists

Tags: reactjs, typescript, filter

```
const items1 = [ 
{ 
"_id": "621b91571730315e", 
"movieName": "example movie",
 },
...
]
```

```
const items2 = 
[ { 
"_id": "641dad8d176f6c96f", 
"MovieId": "621b91571730315656b7aa61", 
}, 
{ 
"_id": "641f5270176f6c96f", 
"movieId": "621b91571730315e",
 } ,
...
]
```

I have an object in two lists named item1 and item2, I rendered the 2nd one in the dom and while searching, I search by keyword, but because I have it as id, I have to search with id. I wanted to set it but I can't. So as a result, I have to search with MovieName instead of MovieId and I have to use items2. Any idea what should I do?

```
useEffect(() => { 
if (keyword) { 
const result = search(items2, keyword, [ "MovieId", ]); 
 setData(result); 
} else {
 setData(items2);
 } 
}, [keyword, items2]);
```

This is the search function I use to search.

```
export const search = (data: any[], keyword: string, fields: string[]) => { 
if (keyword) {
 return data.filter((i) => { 
   return fields.some((f) => { 
     return i[f] 
       ?.toString() 
       .toLocaleLowerCase() 
       .includes(keyword.toString().toLocaleLowerCase()) 
      }) 
    }) 
 } 
 return data 
};
```

I write a lot of code with filter, map, find functions, most of them gave errors or I couldn't get the result I wanted.

This was the closest I got to the solution. I couldn't find the solution because it is undefined in the list.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (keyword) {
      const resultItem1 = search(item1, keyword, ["movieName"]);
      const result = items2.map((item) => {
        const [x] = resultItem1.filter(
          (movie) => item.MovieId === items._id
        );
        return x;
      });
      setData(x)
    } else {
      setData(items);
    }
  }, [keyword, items1, items2]);
```

Comment: Why not just have the `movieName` in the same object as `_id` and `MovieId`

Comment: The api I use is written like this and they have other endpoints depending on each other.